# Getting "Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed" on my Laravel API from Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, rest, cors

I've developed an API with Laravel which worked perfect with Postman, and I'm now developing its front-end with Angular.

I'm currently getting this error each time I send a request to the API: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/master-fullstack/api-rest-laravel/public/api/user/update. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed).`

I already have set CORS properly in my laravel project:

**index.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

This is what I have in my Angular project:

**user.service.ts**

```
update(token: string, user: any) {
  let json = JSON.stringify(user);
  let params = "json="+json;
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', token);
  return this._http.put(this.url + 'user/update', params, {headers: headers});
}
```

It looks like the issue is about having multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, but I just have one, because if I remove it, I get this another error: `CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`

I have also tried replacing `*` for `http://localhost:4200`, but the issue still persists!

I don't understand what's going on.

Thanks.

**Fixed**! I've had to add this code to `httpd.conf`.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

And then, I've enabled headers module on Apache (WampServer -> Apache -> Apache Modules -> headers_module).

Answer (score 1):

you have to add

```
"Accept": "application/json"
```

to your request headers

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I have tried adding `.append("Accept", "application/json")` to my HttpHeaders, and the issue still persists.

Comment: Fixed! I've added the workaround on my main post. It was just about configuring Apache.